# Install package "locClass" in R

Tags: r

I want to install a package named "locClass" in R but always failed and kept getting the following warning:

> install.packages("locClass", repos="http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/")

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘locClass’
These will not be installed
```

The install command is referred to: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1187

Also, I downloaded the package source from the above website. But R returned the following:

> library(locClass)

```
Error in library(locClass) : ‘locClass’ is not a valid installed package
```

My R version is 3.3.3. I tried the 3.4.0 but failed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a solution but an alternative to utilize functionality of package **locClass**. Download the package file of *locClass* from [here](https://github.com/rforge/locclass) and `source(functions.R)` present [here](https://github.com/rforge/locclass/tree/master/pkg/locClass/R). This way you can use all functions available in package.

Note : `function.R` means `FLXMCL.R`, `FLXMCLconstant.R` etc.

I'm still looking for a better solution but this is a temporary alternative.